# remove text from string that is within different types of quotation marks

Tags: jquery, regex

I would like to remove text within a string that is within quotation marks. The following does the job, but I need to amend it so that it also includes quotation marks such as

```
"", '', ``,`´ and «
```

because it's different per language.

```
var s= "Socken ´Marc Colours` aus Baumwollkomposition"
s= s.replace(/ +´.+` +/g,' ');
```

How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: u need a function that should take input string , and remove the text inside tht string?

Answer (score 1):

You could use brackets (`[` and `]`) to specify groups of characters, where **any character** from the group needs to match. For instance:

```
s = s.replace(/\s*[´"].*?[`"]\s*/g,' ');
```

This regex explained:

```
\s*    ; any whitespace
[´"]   ; followed by either ´ or " (add more characters here if needed)
.*?    ; and any text
[`"]   ; up to the closing ` or " (add more characters here if needed)
\s*    ; and finally any trailing whitespace
```

As you can see, you can expand the list of characters considered to be quotations by putting them into the `[´"]` groups. For instance, `[12]` matches either `1` or `2`, while `[24ab]` matches either `2`, `4`, `a` or `b`.

Quick Google search returns a nice explanation on how `[` and `]` work:

> POSIX bracket expressions are a special kind of character classes. POSIX bracket expressions match one character out of a set of characters, just like regular character classes. They use the same syntax with square brackets. A hyphen creates a range, and a caret at the start negates the bracket expression.

([source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html)).

Comment: You forgot to add single quotes ' and «.

Comment: but does this remove the text within the quotation marks too?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen- well, I intended to show how to accomplish the task. It's trivial to just add those signs in between `[` and `]` signs. That's why I added the explanation :)

Comment: @user1937021 - yes, the `.*?` part matches the text withing the quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet will remove all words in your text inside the four types of quotation marks you gave in your question.  Notice that the match is non-greedy, meaning it will match every opening quotation mark with the **closest** closing quotation mark.

```
var s = s.replace(/['"`«].*?['"´»]/g, "");
```

Comment: but does this remove the text within the quotation marks too?